# PHP - Sort records using radiobuttons?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a site which searches for hotels based on type of hotel, keyword, location and price. Everything works fine except sorting. I'm able to sort the results before displaying them; however, after they are displayed I cannot do anything to re-sort them.

NOTE: I AM USING REAL ESTATE WORDPRESS THEME FROM TEMPLATIC.

Here is the php code that retrieves records from db and sort them either by price or by date, depending on $sort type value.

```
<?php   
$sort type=0; //0-sort by price ... 1-sort by date
...
if ($sort_type == 0) {
$srch_sql .= "  order by abs(o.meta_value) asc limit $startlimit , $posts_per_page";
}
elseif ($sort_type == 1){
$srch_sql .= "  order by p.id desc limit $startlimit , $posts_per_page";
}
?>
```

I know there should be at least one solution for this. The one I am thinking of right now is to have two radio buttons. One for sorting by date and the other by price.

```
<input type="radio" name="sort_type" value="Price">Price</input>
<input type="radio" name="sort_type" value="Date">Date</input>
```

However, the problem with this one is that I DON'T KNOW HOW assign values (1 and 0) to variable $sort_type when the selection is changed from one radiobutton to the other one and to reload the page without the variable $sort_type resetting to 0 when page is reloaded.

Any sugestions!?

ENTIRE CODE BELOW

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if (is_paged()) $is_paged = true; ?>

<div class="wrapper" >
    <div class="clearfix container_border">
           <div class="breadcrumbs">
            <p><?php if ( get_option( 'ptthemes_breadcrumbs' )) { yoast_breadcrumb('',''); } ?></p>
                <span class="findproperties" onclick="show_hide_propertysearchoptions();"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><?php _e(FIND_PROPERTIES_TEXT);?></a></span>
            </div>
        </div>

<?php require_once (TEMPLATEPATH . '/library/includes/search.php');  ?>




 <?php  
    //sort_type = 0 order by price
    //sort_type = 1 order by date
    $sort_type = 0; ?>


     // this part of the code retrieves data from db
 <?php  
    $is_search = 0;
    global $wpdb;
    $totalpost_count = 0;
    $propertycategory = get_cat_id_from_name(get_option('ptthemes_propertycategory'));
    $propertycategorys = get_sub_categories($propertycategory,'string');
    $all_pids_arr = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT group_concat(ID) FROM $wpdb->posts where post_status='publish'");
    $all_pids_arr = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT tr.object_id FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt join $wpdb->term_relationships tr on tr.term_taxonomy_id=tt.term_taxonomy_id where tt.term_id in ($propertycategorys)");
    if($_REQUEST['srch_location'])
    {
        $is_search = 1;
        $srch_location = $_REQUEST['srch_location'];
        $location_pids_arr = $wpdb->get_col("select post_id from $wpdb->postmeta where meta_key like 'add_location' and meta_value like \"$srch_location\"");
        $all_pids_arr = array_intersect($all_pids_arr,$location_pids_arr);
    }
    if($_REQUEST['srch_price'])
    {
        $is_search = 1;
        $srch_price = $_REQUEST['srch_price'];
        if(strstr($srch_price,'-'))
        {
            $srch_price_str = str_replace('-',' and ',$srch_price);
            $srch_price_arr = $wpdb->get_col("select post_id from $wpdb->postmeta where meta_key like 'price' and meta_value between $srch_price_str");
        }
        elseif(strstr($srch_price,'+'))
        {
            $srch_price_str = str_replace('+','',$srch_price);
            $srch_price_arr = $wpdb->get_col("select post_id from $wpdb->postmeta where meta_key like 'price' and meta_value >= $srch_price_str");
        }           
        $all_pids_arr = array_intersect($all_pids_arr,$srch_price_arr);
    }

    if($_REQUEST['srch_type'])
    {
        $is_search = 1;
        $srch_type = $_REQUEST['srch_type'];
        $type_pids_arr = $wpdb->get_col("select post_id from $wpdb->postmeta where meta_key like 'property_type' and meta_value = \"$srch_type\"");
        $all_pids_arr = array_intersect($all_pids_arr,$type_pids_arr);
    }

    if($_REQUEST['srch_keyword'] && $_REQUEST['srch_keyword']!=CITY_STATE_ZIP_SRCH_TEXT)
    {
        $is_search = 1;
        $srch_keyword = $_REQUEST['srch_keyword'];

        $kw_pids_arr = $wpdb->get_col("select id from $wpdb->posts where post_title like \"%$srch_keyword%\"");

        $all_pids_arr = array_intersect($all_pids_arr,$kw_pids_arr);
    }

    if($is_search && !$all_pids_arr)
    {
        $all_pids_arr[0] = 'nopost';
    }
    if($_REQUEST['srch_property_id'])
    {
        $post_ids_str = $_REQUEST['srch_property_id'];
        $sub_cat_sql .= " and p.ID in ($post_ids_str) ";
    }else
    {
        if($all_pids_arr)
        {
            $post_ids_str = implode(',',$all_pids_arr);
            if($post_ids_str)
            {
                $sub_cat_sql .= " and p.ID in ($post_ids_str) ";
            }
        }   
    }
    $featurecat = get_cat_id_from_name(get_option('ptthemes_featuredcategory'));
    if($featurecat)
    {
        $srch_feature_pids = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT group_concat(tr.object_id) FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt join $wpdb->term_relationships tr on tr.term_taxonomy_id=tt.term_taxonomy_id where tt.term_id in ($featurecat)");
        $srch_feature_pids = '';
    }
    $blogcat = get_cat_id_from_name(get_option('ptthemes_blogcategory'));
    $blogcatcatids = get_sub_categories($blogcat,'string');
    if($blogcatcatids)
    {
        $srch_blog_pids = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT group_concat(tr.object_id) FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt join $wpdb->term_relationships tr on tr.term_taxonomy_id=tt.term_taxonomy_id where tt.term_id in ($blogcatcatids)");
    }
    if($srch_blog_pids && $srch_feature_pids)
    {
        $sub_cat_sql .= " and p.ID not in ($srch_blog_pids,$srch_feature_pids) ";
    }elseif($srch_blog_pids && $srch_feature_pids=='')
    {
        $sub_cat_sql .= " and p.ID not in ($srch_blog_pids) ";
    }elseif($srch_blog_pids=='' && $srch_feature_pids)
    {
        $sub_cat_sql .= " and p.ID not in ($srch_feature_pids) ";
    }

    $srch_sql = "select p.* from $wpdb->posts p join $wpdb->postmeta o on p.ID=o.post_id $post_meta_join where p.post_status='publish' and p.post_type='post' and o.meta_key='price'  $sub_cat_sql";
    if($srch_feature_pids)
    {
        $feature_srch_sql = "select p.* from $wpdb->posts p join $wpdb->postmeta o on p.ID=o.post_id $post_meta_join where p.post_status='publish' and p.post_type='post' and o.meta_key='price' and p.ID in ($srch_feature_pids)";
        $srch_sql = " select * from (($feature_srch_sql) union ($srch_sql))";
    }

    $totalpost_count = $wpdb->get_var("select count(p.ID) from $wpdb->posts p join $wpdb->postmeta o on p.ID=o.post_id $post_meta_join where p.post_status='publish' and p.post_type='post' and o.meta_key='price'  $sub_cat_sql");
    global $posts_per_page,$paged;
    if($paged==''){$paged=1;}
    $startlimit = $posts_per_page*($paged-1);

    if ($sort_type == 0) {
    $srch_sql .= "  order by abs(o.meta_value) asc limit $startlimit , $posts_per_page";
    }
    elseif ($sort_type == 1){
    $srch_sql .= "  order by p.id desc limit $startlimit , $posts_per_page";
    }

    $post_info = $wpdb->get_results($srch_sql);

    ?><!-- contentarea #end --> 



<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/library/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/library/js/functions.js"></script>

<div class="contentarea">
<div class="content" >
<div class="latestproperties latestproperties_<?php echo stripslashes(get_option('ptthemes_sidebar_left'));  ?>">



<p align="right">Order by:
<input type="radio" name="order" value="Price" />Price</input>
<input type="radio" name="order" value="Date" />Date</input></p>

    <h5><span><a href="#" class="switch_thumb"><?php _e(SWITCH_THUMB_TEXT);?></a></span>

    <?php
    if($_REQUEST['s'] == 'shfleto te gjitha')
    {
        _e(LATEST_PROPERTIES_BYPRICE_TEXT);
    }
    elseif(is_category() && $_REQUEST['search']=='')
    {
        echo single_cat_title();
    }else
    {
        echo get_search_param();
    }   
    ?></h5>     


    <?php if($post_info) { ?>               
    <ul class="display ">
    <?php
    $count=0;
    foreach($post_info as $post_info_obj)
    {
        $count++;
        $post = $post_info_obj;
        get_property_info_li($post);
        if($count%3==0)
        {
        ?>
        <li class="blank"></li>
        <?php   
        }
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
        }else
        {
            _e(NO_PROPERTY_AVAILABLE_MSG);
            if($_POST['search']=='search')
            {
                echo get_search_param();
            }
        }
        ?>
    <?php if($post_info) { ?>
    <div class="pagination">
<?php if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { ?><?php wp_pagenavi(); ?><?php } ?>
     </div>
    <?php }?>
</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>  <!-- sidebar #end -->
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Please give us a concise, relevant piece of code which demonstrates your problem. Don't just throw your entire app at us and expect us to find the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use jquery to load the data into a div on the page on click of the radio buttons. Something like this:

```
<input type='radio' onselect='showResults("date")'/><br/>
<input type='radio' onselect='showResults("price")'/><br/>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function showResults(sortField){
        $('#results_container').load('results_page.php?sort='+sortField);

    }
</script>


<div id='results_container'></div>
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but being honest I cannot implement it. So, is it possible and acceptable for you if I put the whole code and you tell me exactly how to do it. Highly appreciate it.

Comment: Create a file that only does the search, and generates the html for the search results. Leave out all html above 

<?php if($post_info) { ?>               
    <ul class="display ">
    <?php , including the header, html tags, etc. 
 Then when you load the page via jquery, it will show just the results inside your results_container div.